# How to dig into an certain hash depth?

Tags: perl, hash

I have a hash where I don't know its depth. I got it with `DBI::selectall_hashref` where the second parameter is given by the user.

So depending on the query I can have something like this for a 2-levels hash.

```
hash_ref = (
   aphrodite => (
      foo => (
         name => aphrodite,
         foobar => foo
         a => 1,
         b => 2,
      )
      bar => (
         name => aphrodite,
         foobar => bar
         a => 1,
         b => 2,
      )
   )
   apollo => (
      ...
   )
   ares => (
      ...
   )
)
```

As you can see the `key` columns are redundant into the hash. I would like to remove the redundant keys.

If I know that this is a 2-levels hash I can easily solve my problem with this:

```
for my $name (keys $hash_ref) {
    for my $foobar (keys $hash_ref->{$name}) {
        my $h = $hash_ref->{$name}{$foobar};
        delete $h->{name};
        delete $h->{foobar};
    }
}
```

However with a 3-levels hash I will need 3 cascaded for-loop and so on.

> How can I dynamically remove the redundant keys from `$hash_ref` *i.e.* `name` and `foobar`?

My initial idea was to recursively iterate trough my hash:

```
iterate($hash_ref, scalar @keys);
sub iterate {
    my ($ref, $depth) = @_;
    for(keys $ref) {
        if ($depth > 0) { 
            iterate($ref->{$_}, $depth - 1);  
        } 
        else {
            delete $ref->{$_} for(@keys);
        }
    }
}
```

It works but It's ugly, very ugly... Before going any further I would like to know if I missed something. Perhaps the solution could be much simpler that I think.

Any ideas?

#### More details?

I am writing a database fetcher that takes a user configuration that contains the SQL query `$sql` and the hash keys `@keys`. So I get the values from the database with:

```
$dbh->selecthall_hashref($sql, \@keys, {}, @bind);
```

I also have to clean fetched data according to additional. Do apply these rules, I have to iterate into the deepest level of `$hash_ref` to access the keys/values.

Comment: You can't remove the elements from the record detail without inspecting the `@keys` array, but all you need is `delete @{$h}{@keys}`. It looks like you should be using `$dbh->selectall_arrayref( $sql, { Slice => {} } )` instead. That way you get just an array of hashes without the upper level keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you need. Essentially it recurses through the hash until it finds a layer where the hash values aren't references. Then it removes the elements from that layer with the keys in `@keys`

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use 5.010;

use Data::Dump;
use List::Util 'any';

my $hash_ref = {
  aphrodite => {
    bar => { name => "aphrodite", foobar => "bar", a => 3, b => 4, },
    foo => { name => "aphrodite", foobar => "foo", a => 1, b => 2, },
  },
  apollo => {
    bar => { name => "apollo",    foobar => "bar", a => 7, b => 8, },
    foo => { name => "apollo",    foobar => "foo", a => 5, b => 6, },
  },
  ares => {
    bar => { name => "ares",      foobar => "bar", a => 11, b => 12, },
    foo => { name => "ares",      foobar => "foo", a => 9,  b => 10, },
  },
};

my @keys = qw/ name foobar /;

remove_dups($hash_ref, \@keys);

dd $hash_ref;

sub remove_dups {
  my ($href, $keys) = @_;
  if ( any { ref } values %$href ) {
    remove_dups($_, $keys) for values %$href;
  }
  else {
    delete @{$href}{@$keys};
  }
}
```

**output**

```
{
  aphrodite => { bar => { a => 3, b => 4 }, foo => { a => 1, b => 2 } },
  apollo => { bar => { a => 7, b => 8 }, foo => { a => 5, b => 6 } },
  ares => { bar => { a => 11, b => 12 }, foo => { a => 9, b => 10 } },
}
```

Comment: Everytime you answer my questions I learn so many things with Perl. Thank you Borodin. I didn't know `any` from `List::Util` and `@{$href}{@$keys}` is pretty.

Comment: @nowox: That's good to hear. Thank you, I'm glad to help. `any` is much the same as `grep` except that it stops checking as soon as it finds an item in the list that matches the criterion. `grep` just checks all the items regardless